# Convert signed char[] to unsigned char[] in C

Tags: c, char

I would like to convert an array of signed char to an array of unsigned char in C. How can I do it ?

Comment: What do you mean saying "to convert"?

Comment: Please see: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496). What may be confusing you is that [Stack Overflow is not like all those other sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/172496)

Comment: I think instead of give full answer,wait for the author of thread show what he have tried and then points a way.

Comment: I'd think it's casting what was searched for https://stackoverflow.com/a/5042335/2932052

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use memcpy?

```
unsigned char uChars[count];
signed char sChars[count];

memcpy(uChars, sChars, count);
```

Comment: +1. Is `char foo[x]` of `signed` type by default,right?

Comment: @Jack Implementation-dependent.