# std::basic_fstream::put() has no effect

Tags: c++, fstream

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: basics <file>" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::basic_fstream<unsigned char> stream;

    stream.open(argv[1], std::fstream::out);
    stream.put('T');
    stream.put('E');
    stream.put('S');
    stream.put('T');
    stream.flush();
    stream.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The file is being created but there is nothing inside it when I open it in an editor.
My compiler is `gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)`.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: You should probably check that the writing actually succeeds.

Comment: Interestingly, changing from `unsigned char` template parameter to just `char` (as `std::fstream` is typedefed) solves the issue. I'm not 100% sure why though; I'd have to delve into the STL bowels to figure that one out.

Comment: Standard streams are only guaranteed to have specializations with `char` and `wchar_t`.

Comment: You don't need to flush and close, the stream does that when it dies.

Comment: The template argument should be `char` not `unsigned char` if your printing characters, see [what is an unsigned char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char)

Comment: works with Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @JamesMoore it is unsigned char in order to be able to use binary data. I cut out all that stuff to have a lightweight example. The real code works with binary data and I don't only store characters, I store literally everything since it is intended to become a database when it's finished. I would use char if I knew a cast from unsigned to signed that works lossless in terms of a 1:1 binary layout of the data.

Comment: @molbdnilo I added the flush because I thought it was worth trying. So in order to prevent comments like 'try flushing' I left it in here :P

Comment: @JamesMoore I just read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040920/converting-from-signed-char-to-unsigned-char-and-back-again). It describes how to cast `char` to `unsigned char` and vice versa.

Comment: Never the less I think not being able to use anything except `char` and `wchar_t` somewhat violates the paradigm of streams.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [std::basic_ostream::put](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put)

> Unlike formatted output functions, this function does not set the failbit if the output fails.

Even if you check the stream state there won't be any error shown. However, if you try to write something with a *formatted* output operation, a `std::bad_cast` exception will be thrown because, among the possible reasons, there is no facet corresponding for that locale, which is checked when that operation is done.

Raw operations do not care about localization therefore it can't fail for that reason, while it would if e.g the raw write failed.

[std::has_facet](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/has_facet)

> **Exceptions**
>   std::bad_cast if std::has_facet(loc) == false.

Indeed, `std::ctype` is specialized for `char` and `wchar_t` not `unsigned char` which you will have to manually do. For `en_GB.utf8`, `std::has_facet<std::ctype<unsigned char>>( std::locale("en_GB.utf8") ) == false`