# C++ cast unsigned to signed

Tags: c++, arduino, reinterpret-cast

I tried to replicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5042335) but it would not compile.

```
unsigned char x = 0;
reinterpret_cast<signed char>(x);
```

It says

```
C:\Users\SXG5558\Documents\Arduino\sketch_jun30a\sketch_jun30a.ino: In function 'void setup()':

sketch_jun30a:3: error: invalid cast from type 'unsigned char' to type 'signed char'

     reinterpret_cast<signed char>(x);

                                    ^

exit status 1
```

EDIT:

To be clear, I really do want to reinterpret the bits in memory from signed to unsigned. I am writing an I2C library that reads and writes unsigned data, but I am using that library to control sensors which are signed, so I want to reinterpret cast the actual data.

Comment: the example you linked has `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char&>(x);`. Note the `&`

Comment: Isn't your question title just demanding the opposite casting direction as shown in your code?

Comment: just use the nuke-it `(signed char)x` cast.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I edited the title to reflect that

Comment: @pm100 The C-style cast would be a static cast, but I want a reinterpret cast

Comment: gonna do exactly what you want tho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant part from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) is

> Type aliasing
>
> When a pointer or reference to object whose dynamic type is DynamicType is reinterpret_cast (or C-style cast) to a pointer or reference to object of a different type AliasedType, the cast always succeeds, but the resulting pointer or reference may only be used to access the object if one of the following is true:
>
> [...]
>
> - AliasedType is the (possibly cv-qualified) signed or unsigned variant of DynamicType
>
> [...]

ie. you forgot the `&` from the example you linked.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for answering a stupid question.

Comment: @Sam actually it is not such a stupid question. I needed some time to understand why it does not work without the `&` and I still could not explain it...

Comment: I think it is so that assignment goes through properly (eg. `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(x) = 10`). That begs the question, what if you don't want this functionality? How can you cast `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(f())` without assigning the result of `f()` to a temporary variable.